# What are the Android Versions offered by Genymotion emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

I'm an android developer and was contemplating using genymotion for emulating. I wanted to know what are the APIs/Android Versions that it covers. If anyone uses Genymotion please provide some info on the same. Also it would be nice if you could enlighten me on some of the benefits/advantages that you have noticed over the stock emulator .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android version

- 2.3.7
- 4.1.1
- 4.2.2
- 4.3
- 4.4.2

P.S Guide [Installing ARM Translation and GApps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952)

Comment: There is no V 2.3.7 in 2018 version list!